# Cómo introducir y validar 'EOF' en NetBeans

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un código que funciona, no hace falta poner el código pero lo pongo de igual manera

```
try{
      while ((car = (char)System.in.read()) != eof){
//mas código
}catch(IOException e){}
```

el problema empieza aquí, tengo declarado esto:

`final char eof = (char)-1;`

(trabajo con Netbeans 8.2)

el programa corre perfectamente, pero al trabajar en la pantalla de este IDE se supone que al presionar `CTRL` + `Z` el programa debe finalizar, no soy un experto, es un programa que encontré. Al presionar dichas teclas no funciona, sigue corriendo, debo detenerlo manualmente. ¿por qué pasa eso? ¿cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: Prueba con Ctrl + C o Ctrl + D, dependiendo del SO que uses.

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes exactamente con la línea `final char eof = (char)-1;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estrictamente hablando `EOF` es una [macro](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/EOF/) definida como un entero con un valor negativo (por lo general, -1). Normalmente es devuelto por las funciones que realizan las operaciones de lectura para denotar un error o el final de la entrada.

No existe un método abreviado para introducir `EOF`. Pero un programa (Terminal o Símbolo de Sistema) puede **recibir** una combinación <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> o <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, y lo puede **traducir** a `EOF`.

[image: icon] NetBeans no es capaz de interpretar correctamente <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> o <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, pero
[[image: icon] **eclipse**](http://www.eclipse.org/) sí lo hace. Esto se puede comprobar utilizando un programa simple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(System.in.read());
    System.out.println(System.in.read());
}
```

Por otra parte, cuando declaras lo siguiente:

```
final char eof = (char)-1;
```

En realidad, no estás definiendo el *carácter* `EOF`. Estás definiendo tu variable como un carácter (**`char`**) y como tal no existen caracteres con valores negativos. Lo que tu variable contiene es en realidad `\uFFFF`, el cual no representa *formalmente* ningún carácter, aunque sí está dentro del bloque de [Especiales en Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)).

Lo mejor sería verificar el valor entero. Esto es (por ejemplo):

```
for (int c; (c = System.in.read()) != -1;) {
    car = (char) c;

    // Más código
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no reconoce el ctr+z, yo lo solucioné indicando al programa en un If que finalizará la captura de datos cuando el usuario tecle el caracter #, el if anidado tiene un break que finaliza la entrada del flujo de datos:

public class ContarPalabras {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Declaración de variables
    final char eof = (char)-1; //Final asigna un valor constante a la variable eof
    char car;
    boolean palabra = false;
    int ncaracteres = 0, npalabras = 0, nlineas = 0;

    try{
        //Encabezado de la aplicación
        System.out.println("Introducir texto. "+
                "Pulse Enter después de cada linea." +
                "Para finalizar la captura teclea el caracter #" 
                );

        /*Inicio del bucle principal que lee la cadena de carateres sin
        importar si se dió una vuelta de carro creando un bucle infinito
        que solo se interrumpe con ctr + z*/
        while(  ( car =(char)System.in.read() )  != eof){

            if (car == '#') break;

            /*Bucle 1 que detecta vuelta de carro. Contará caracteres hasta
            detectar una vuelta de carro, donde la variable ncarateres se
            autoincrementará de uno en uno dando el número de caracteres 
            del texto dado, eof identifica el final del flujo de entrada*/
            if(car == '\r') continue;
            ncaracteres++;

            /*Bucle 2 que detecta los espacios en blanco, inicio de lineas
            nuevas y tabuladores, los cuales discrimina al asignarles un
            valor boolean false*/
            if (car == ' ' || car == '\n' || car == '\t')
                palabra = false;

            /*Bucle 3, el operador ! es negación, asigna un incremento a la
            variable npalabras cuando la variable boolean palabra es true*/
            else if(!palabra){
                npalabras++;
                palabra = true;
            }//Cierre else if

            /*Bucle 4, identifica el comienzo de una nueva linea, donde
            el valor de nlineas se autoincrementa*/
            if(car == '\n')
                nlineas++;

        }//Cierre del bucle principal while

        //Presentación de resultados
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Caracteres = " + ncaracteres +
                           "  Palabras= "    + npalabras   +
                           "  Lineas= "      + nlineas      );


    }//Cierre try

    catch(IOException ignorada){}


}//Cierre programa
```

}//Cierre clase